# How do I change categorical data into binary data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I wanted to change categorical data into binary data.
My data looks like this

> data=[[1,2,3,....],[2,3,4,...],[3,8,5,....],........]

Here 1 and 2 doesn't have any connection so I have to treat these numbers as categorical data.

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

converted_val = data.T.to_dict().values()

vectorizer = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)

vec_x = vectorizer.fit_transform( converted_val )
```

The result I am expecting is:

> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8......
>
> 1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,....
>
> 0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,....
>
> 0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,....
>
> ....................]

Any help to get this answer would be great or some suggestion to solve this problem would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to make a vector which indicate the number of occurrence of each value in an input vector without considerration for a position of the value.  My solution is using `CountVectorizer`. `CountVectorizer` is designed for `string`. To apply `CountVectorizer` to numeric vector I pass some arguments to `CountVectorizer` below as.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

data = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,30],[2,30,4],[3,8,5]])
converted_val = data.as_matrix()

vectorizer = CountVectorizer( lowercase=False, tokenizer = lambda x:x )

vec_x = vectorizer.fit_transform( converted_val )
```

Checking by the code below as:

```
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names()) 
print(vec_x.toarray())
```

The output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 30]
[[1 1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 1 1 0]]
```